# Is it possible to change div content to php script, and get back data from that script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a calendar application for my web page.

I want to make this calendar can be browse easily within months or years without refreshing the page.

HTML :

```
    <select id="monthselect">
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="yearselect">
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" id="month-submit" value="Select Month">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="month-next" value="Next Month">
    <input type="submit" id="month-prev" value="Previous Month">
    <div id="month-data">
        Place for calendar
    </div>
```

Scripts :

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
```

I want to change the content in month-data div using calendar.php, which is the function of the  calendar, when the month selected.

But, I also have 2 more buttons which is previous and next month. The problem is, after I get the calendar from selected month and year, when I press the next button, I can't get information from what's the month & year is currently displayed on page.

here is my global.js javascript:

```
$('input#month-submit').on('click',function(){
    var month=$('select#monthselect').val();
    var year=$('select#yearselect').val();
    // $.post('ajax/calendar.php',{month:month},function(){
        $('div#month-data').load('ajax/calendar.php?month='+month+'&year='+year);

    // });
});

$('input#month-next').click(function(){
    if(month==12){
        ++year;
        month=0;
    }
    ++month;

    $('div#month-data').load('ajax/calendar.php?month='+month+'&year='+year);
});
$('input#month-prev').click(function(){
            if(month==1){
            --year;
            month=13;
        }
        --month;
    $('div#month-data').load('ajax/calendar.php?month='+month+'&year='+year);
});
```

How can i fix this? or is there any alternative logic to create my calendar application?

thank you

Comment: What happens if you make 'month' and 'year' global variables (i.e. remove 'var' in front of them) inside your first function?

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery UI datepicker:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/ocgy6bez/

```
<input id="myDate"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
</script>
```